# UPDATE: Article ID error when connecting to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating an email form that will allow comments to be posted to a localhost server.

I have three PHP files:

- `page1.php` and `page2.php` contain the form and display the comments.
- `manage_comments.php` contains the code that will connect the form to the server.

The `manage_comments.php` file is where I have the problem. I received an error code after submitting the form.

> Errorcode: 1193 invalid article id

The **article id** is referring to the ids for `page1.php` and `page2.php`, which are "1" and "2" respectively.

```
mywebsite.com/page1.php?id=1, mywebsite.com/page2.php?id=2
```

In the tutorial for the form, I was instructed to write a hidden value that would hold the article's id.

```
<form>
    <input type='hidden' name='articleid' id='articleid' value='<? echo $_GET["id"]; ?> />
</form>
```

Then in `manage_comments.php`, the tutorial instructed me to write this:

```
  $articleid = $_GET['id'];

  if( ! is_numeric($articleid) )
      die('invalid article id');
```

---

I changed my code and I still received the 1193 error. The tutorial was written before "mysqli" and I had to make convert the code from mysql to mysqli. Here is the code from manage_comments.php:

```
      <?

      if( $_POST )
      {

      $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'sosdeff', 'edflash9', 'sosdeff_testerforms');

      /* check connection */
      if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
      }

      if (!mysqli_query($mysqli, "SET a=1")) {
      printf("Errorcode: %d\n", mysqli_errno($mysqli));
      }

      mysqli_select_db($mysqli, "sosdeff_testerforms");

      $users_name = $_POST['name'];
      $users_email = $_POST['email'];
      $users_website = $_POST['website'];
      $users_comment = $_POST['comment'];

      $users_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $users_name);
      $users_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $users_email);
      $users_website = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $users_website);
      $users_comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $users_comment);

      $articleid = $_GET['articleid'];

      if( ! is_numeric($articleid) )

      die('invalid article id');

      $query = "INSERT INTO `sosdeff_testerforms`,`comments` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `website`, `comment`, `timestamp`, `articleid`)

     mysqli_query($query);
     echo "<h2>Thank you for your Comment!</h2>";
     mysqli_close($mysqli);

     }
     ?>
```

Comment: This `value='<? echo $_GET["id"]; ?>` make sure that open short tags are on, otherwise do `value='<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>'` plus, you had a missing quote.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Okay what do you mean by open short tags are on?

Comment: You're welcome. In PHP, this `<?` is equivalent to `<?php` if they are on. If they are not, then that will cause problems. Also, to echo in open short tag method, instead of echo, you can do `<?=`

Answer (score 1):

In your form the field is called `articleid`.

After the form submission the id is empty as there's no `id` field in the form, only `articleid`

In `manage_comments.php`, change your code to:

```
$articleid = $_GET['articleid'];

if( ! is_numeric($articleid) )
    die('invalid article id');
```